# Serverless framework is ignoring CLI options

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I'm trying to dynamically pass in options to resolve when deploying my functions with serverless but they're always null or hit the fallback.

```
custom:
  send_grid_api: ${opt:sendgridapi, 'missing'}
  SubscribedUsersTable:
    name: !Ref UsersSubscriptionTable
    arn: !GetAtt UsersSubscriptionTable.Arn
  bundle:
    linting: false

provider:
  name: aws
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  memorySize: 256
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: us-west-2
  environment:
    STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    SEND_GRID_API_KEY: ${self:custom.send_grid_api}
```

I've also tried:

```
  environment:
    STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    SEND_GRID_API_KEY: ${opt:sendgridapi, 'missing'}
```

both yield 'missing', but why?

```
sls deploy --stage=prod --sendgridapi=xxx
```

also fails if I try with space instead of =.

## Edit: Working Solution

In my github action template, I defined the following:

```
      - name: create env file
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo SEND_GRID_API_KEY=${{ secrets.SEND_GRID_KEY }} >> .env
          ls -la
          pwd
```

In addition, I explicitly set the working directory for this stage like so:

```
working-directory: /home/runner/work/myDir/myDir/
```

In my `serverless.yml` I added the following:

```
  environment:
    SEND_GRID_API_KEY: ${env:SEND_GRID_API_KEY}
```

`sls` will read the contents from the file and load them properly

Comment: You've left out relevant details - and answering inside the question ignores the Q & A format.

Comment: It's not uncommon to incrementally post a potential working solution without answering your own question to provide context to future readers. Your pedanticism with respect to the format is exactly why SO posted this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`opt` is for serverless' CLI options. These are part of `serverless`, not your own code.

You can instead use...

```
provider:
  ...
  environment:
    ... 
    SEND_GRID_API_KEY: ${env:SEND_GRID_API_KEY}
```

And pass the value as an environment variable in your deploy step.

```yaml
- name: Deploy
  run: sls deploy --stage=prod
  env:
    SEND_GRID_API_KEY: "insert api key here"
```

Comment: Thanks Noel. Is there a difference between env and environment? I tried env to no avail and not seeing environment in their docs in this format. This solution wasn't interpolating for me.